# Could we strtotime() with a variable contianing only month and the day of the year and get the textual representation of the day of the week from it?

Tags: php

Could we strtotime() with a variable contianing only month and the day of the year and get the textual representation of the day of the week from it? ?
this is my try:

```
function something
{
    $sale_date=date('md');
    if($this->isSat($sale_date))
    {
        ------;
    }
}


function isSat($sale_date)
{
    $sale_date_time=strtotime($sale_date);
    $day=date('l',$sale_date_time);
    if($day=='Saturday')
    {return true;}
}
```

Comment: You can see a list of acceptable formats for strtotime to parse [here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php)

Comment: *scratches head* containing only the month and the day name? Then no, not accurate as it will be a 1 out of 4 chance you guessed it correctly. But I will be scratching my head again on the question of why there isn't a timestamp stored?

Comment: `$sale_date_time=strtotime($sale_date);
    $day=date('l',$sale_date_time); ` works, but sale date need to bee a complete date. You can't tell the day of the week you you don't say the specific day

Comment: You can test this pretty easily, https://eval.in/628830. Without the year it is going to assume it is the current year.

Comment: **If you think about this logically** How can you tell what day of the week it will be **if you dont know what year it is** The first of April  _Intensionally used_ is not on the same day every year!!!!

Comment: `function isSat($sale_date)
{
    
    $sale_date_time=DateTime::createFromFormat('md', $sale_date);
    
    return ($sale_date_time->format('l') == 'Saturday');
}`

Comment: **Come to that** _February 29th_ only occurs every 4 years. **Come on engage brains**

Comment: thanks everyone. i was thinking it would consider current year else could anyone help with making the year current if its not mentioned?

Comment: @MarkBaker, thank you. will this work if the $sale_date is in jan,2017 and we are checking it in 2016? or is there something like to check if the given $sale_date has passed for this year and make it consider the $sale_date of following year?

Comment: @MarkBaker, i added this line before return in ur code:  if(strtotime(date('today'))<$sale_date_time)